# How to get UUID from Android Browser using cordova?

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I installed the latest `cordova` version and I added the platform as `Browser` 
(NOT Android platform). Then I created the Project, then I installed the `cordova` `device information plugin` 
using NPM. Everything okay, but when I ran the Project using **Android Browser**, it did not give the 
**UUID** and serial number also.

Is it possible to get android mobile UUID/any other unique values using android browser without converting it into an app?

Comment: UUID is the universally unique identification for the device...U wont get in the browser. Why you want the values in browser ??

Comment: i need to find the unique users thats why i am looking that UUID. And thanks for clear explain "U wont get in the browser"